# Dynamically Changing Data Source for Crystal Reports in Visual Basic 2019

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, crystal-reports

I am 'revitalizing' an old program I wrote in VB back in 1997 using VB6. It has been quite a journey re-learning all of the new code and I have thoroughly enjoyed it. I have finally hit a little roadblock that I am trying to overcome and perhaps someone has the answer for me. My program is a Gradebook for Teachers and has many reports. The program has the ability to open various "gradebook" DB's (Last years file, another teacher's gradebook, etc...) All DB's are either MDB or ACCDB - it will use either. My reports turned out great and all is well until you open another DB - then the report still points at the DB that was used when I created the report.

In Visual Basic 6, it was as easy as this:

```
Private Sub btnNotesPrint_Click()
   With CrystalReport1
     .ReportFileName = AppDir & "Reports\Notes.RPT"
     .WindowTitle = "Print Student Notes"
     .SelectionFormula = "{STUDENTS.ID} = " & Ids(cboName.ListIndex + 1)
     .DataFiles(0) = PathName & dbname
     .DataFiles(1) = PathName & dbname
   End With
   CLSMDI.CrystalReport1.Action = 1 ' run report
End Sub
```

In Visual Studio 2019, all I have so far is:

```
Private Sub btnPrintContact_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrintContact.Click
   ReportName = AppDir & "\Reports\Student Contact List.RPT"
   ReportSelection = "{Students.StudentID} > 0"
   
   'Display the form with the CrystalReportsViewer on it.
   frmReportViewer.ShowDialog() 
End Sub

-----Which opens the Crystal Report Viewer on 'frmReportViewer' form ----------

Private Sub CrystalReportViewer1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CrystalReportViewer1.Load
   With CrystalReportViewer1
      .ReportSource = ReportName
      .SelectionFormula = ReportSelection
   End With
End Sub
```

---

How do I change the data source that Crystal Report looks at when running the report?  What am I missing?

It's so easy in VB6 so there's got to be an easy solution in VS2019.
I've looked through hundreds of websites and can't find a clean, to the point solution.

Thanks so much,

Michael